# Detect a color change in NSColorPanel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, colors

I have some code that opens a NSColorPanel. How would I be able to detect when the color is changed and then run a callback?

```
NSColorPanel *colorPanel = [NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel];
[colorPanel orderFront:nil];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

You should use target action:

```
NSColorPanel *cp = [NSColorPanel sharedColorPanel];
[cp setTarget:self];
[cp setAction:@selector(colorUpdate:)];
```

and define the action this way:

```
-(void)colorUpdate:(NSColorPanel*)colorPanel{ 
    NSColor* theColor = colorPanel.color;
    ....your code

}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a method `- (void)changeColor:(id)sender`. It sends to the first responder when the user selects a color in an NSColorPanel object. You can override this method in any responder that needs to respond to a color change. May be, it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using KVO? you can observe the `colorPanel` from desired controller; in case of change you will get a callback:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```